# ASP.NET html source download results in single character return for XKCD

Tags: asp.net, webrequest

I'm trying to get the html source for a site using the following code in asp.net:

```
WebRequest webrq = WebRequest.Create("http://www.xkcd.com");

StreamReader str = new StreamReader(webrq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

string pageSrc = str.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

It works for other sites, but for XKCD all I get is a single character �.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Just tried your code and it works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your code up a little more:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.xkcd.com");
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
if (webResponse != null)
{
  var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
  if (responseStream != null)
  {
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var pageSource = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Add a breakpoint at: `if (webResponse != null)` and have a look at the response object. If it looks good, step through to: `if (responseStream != null)` and see what the stream contains.

**The debugger is your friend**. Use it to see what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I just tried that and the following is a snippet of what came up as the pageSource:

Comment: "�\b\0X5-M\0�ks�6�s�+f&��$R�_�\")#K�ŉ_��q;�N$W\"c�P\0вr��~\v��HY��^n�k:2\t�.���e��C�{�\"dIǪ�5�@�1?L�+��j�\"�mWr�\b\0$\t8�:V ��8a<�Ý����x�5z8jڞ��\tt,\t���1�!�X��\0�!�jpٿ������ttv�'V�qnw��3��_�ߜ���]w��\v��\aO�S{�c3>vn�΃B��B�l�ҷ�MEHDgn����` ,i\a@}�K�2�t�`-2�D҈\\\0���cvL&w�C�͵�X藫kI=���5�M#$��C_U���#rz�{�G0\0��罐���� ������h$�'TB~>�L�У�ˡ���@�I�p�h�3�i\b[C8�C�\vQ�;��&�Y�_M5�X�f뇣�������aL��<T\r�2M0.�T�E��d��v�?ӧ��=\t���0��\tp嵅u�&��Vi�\fFhG/��m�qe���\0���᫃���c��ɐ%�l��,p��v�7��m:���=8V�g���]�<�A�'�2]�Oㅶ��^X���Jd7�ㅡ��L�s���ł��C�̵Zx\

Comment: Notice that the webResponse object is actually a HttpWebResponse object? What is it's StatusCode property set to?

Comment: Sorry, was out for lunch. The StatusCode is set to "OK". The weird thing is it only happens with XKCD. All other sites work fine.

Comment: I just found another link to the site that works. Thanks for the help!